# polymer iron-selector multi selector not appearing

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I am trying a simple test of `<iron-selector>` multi select. I ran the demo project that comes with the element and seems to work fine from there, but whenever I copy it to my project, the element does not appear. I've made a Plunker to test it: [Plnkr test link](https://embed.plnkr.co/0F2a1hqMCYG8ZQN9jM8u/). I am trying to test the multi select option (setting and getting the `selected-values`).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/2.3.1/lib/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/2.3.1/lib/paper-toast/paper-toast.html">
  <link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/2.3.1/lib/iron-selector/iron-selector.html">

</head>

<body>
  <p>Start:</p>
  <iron-selector multi selected-values="[0,2]">
    <div>Item 0</div>
    <div>Item 1</div>
    <div>Item 2</div>
    <div>Item 3</div>
    <div>Item 4</div>
  </iron-selector>
  <p>End:</p>

  <paper-toast text="Polymer is working!" opened></paper-toast>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just forgot to style the selected elements. For example, you could style the background of the selected elements to be light gray:

```
<style>
  .iron-selected {
    background: #eee;
  }
</style>
```

[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/5lu76fYgKRDbGWp2xXFC?p=preview)

Comment: Dope...  So <iron-selector> does not need the items to be named? Why does it work different when run under <paper-radio-group>?

Comment: `<paper-radio-group>`'s API requires the `name` attribute to be set, but you could override that to be any attribute name by setting [`attrForSelected`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-radio-group/elements/paper-radio-group#property-attrForSelected). This property actually comes from [`Polymer.IronSelectableBehavior`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-selector/behaviors/Polymer.IronSelectableBehavior#property-attrForSelected), which is not set by `<iron-selector>`.